# Share the logic to implement the gpo change report?

Tags: group-policy, windows

As I need to research to make easy auditing of GPO changes through collections of XML reports of GPO. I wish to compare the XML and produce report like *old values* and *new values* in a table using C# code.

Please share some useful program logic that I could use to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft offers a product that does something very similar to this. Their Desktop Optimization Pack has a component, [Advanced Group Policy Management](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee532079.aspx), which includes a full revision control process for managing changes to GPO. If even includes the ability to roll changes back to previous versions.

I bring this up because change-tracking a GPO is a hard problem. Values can change in the XML, whole files can change without reflection in the XML, and other hard-to-track problems. Microsoft solved this by forcing all GPO changes to be submitted to a central service, which they did by extending the GPO management tools.